# Free alternative to SubtitlesApp for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, video, download-manager, closed-captions

[SubtitlesApp](http://subtitlesapp.com/) recently made a jerk move by transforming a free app on a paid app, while asking users to upgrade to version 3 (which is paid) and not providing the old 2 version for download (and for that I don't want to buy it and support this kind of behaviour).

Anyway, anyone knows a good clone of that app to download subtitles really easily? I really appreciate the simplicity of it: just drag the movie there and that's it, no more clicking.

For those who don't know it: it's a small app where you drag movie files to it (or folders) and it searches for subtitles on your preferred languages, downloads them automatically and puts them near your movie file. All this doesn't require any more click than just dragging the movie.

I tried a few apps but all of them require a few more clicks or don't work.

Comment: Would you accept [Subtitle Videoplayer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/subtitle-videoplayer/naikohapihpbhficdpbddmgbhiccijca?hl=en) as an answer?

Comment: @Huey if this software meets the requirements of the question, then add it as an answer.

Comment: Additional **Warning** I just tested SubTitlesApp (version 3.2.3) based on [a website recommendation](http://lifehacking.nl/productiviteit-tips/ondertiteling-downloaden-zonder-te-zoeken/): installed, started, got the nag screen, closed, and immediately uninstalled it. After that *all my video file associations were gone*!

Answer (score 3):

> **[Sublight](http://www.sublight.me/)** is a powerful free software to manage subtitles that comes with a modern interface and ribbon menu. Not only it can search and download subtitles from multiple sources, Sublight can also edit, synchronize and publish subtitles. After 5 years in active development, Sublight has gained over 100,000 active registered users that constantly provides feedback by rating and reporting the correct or incorrect subtitles.
>
> [image]
>
> Searching for subtitles with Sublight is really easy. You can either choose the video file which it will attempt to determine the title of the video and year that it was released to further assist in locating the correct subtitle, or you can manually search by typing in the keyword. Click the Search subtitles button and within a few seconds the results of available subtitles to download is listed at the bottom. To download, simply right click on the subtitle and select “Download subtitle”. The subtitle file will be automatically downloaded, extracted to the same directory as the video and renamed accordingly.
>
> According to our experience with Sublight, sometimes it takes a few tries to download the correct subtitle that sync with the video because it doesn’t search using hash. Sublight works on Windows and there is both setup and portable version although the portable version is an older build without automatic updates.

---

> **[SubDownloader](http://subdownloader.net/)** is free for Mac OS X and Linux build but weirdly it is a 15 days shareware that cost €15 to purchase a license key. If you hate to search and end up with a subtitle that don’t sync with the downloaded movie, SubDownloader would be your perfect choice because all the found subtitles are 100% matching as it uses file hash. You can either search for subtitles for individual videos or select the whole folder for batch search. It is also possible to search by movie name and upload subtitles to help out the community.
>
> [image]

---

> **[SubiT](http://subit-app.sourceforge.net/)** is a simple and free program that searches for subtitles from multiple sources. The goal of this tool is to download the subtitle as fast as possible without hassle. You can either right click on the video file and select SubiT from the context menu where it will automatically search, download, extract and rename the subtitle file or you can run the program and load the video file from there. The program automatically closes after finished downloading the subtitle. If there are multiple versions available, it will be listed in the Versions box.
>
> [image]
>
> Do take note that by default SubiT searches only the Hebrew version of the subtitle. To change the default language, click on the setting icon located at the bottom right, go to Providers tab and tick on the language that you want to search for. SubiT works on both Windows and Unix operating system.

---

> **[ALLSubtitleSearcher](http://download.cnet.com/ALLSubtitleSearcher/3000-2071_4-75212668.html)** is a subtitle searching tool that has monitoring capabilities. Sometimes a subtitle for certain video takes longer to be created and uploaded to the database websites. Instead of constantly doing a search, you can use ALLSubtitleSearcher to automatically look for the subtitles at selected intervals. There are 2 ways to search for subtitle which is by right clicking on the video file and select ALLSubtitleSearcher or you can click the Add title button from the program.
>
> [image]
>
> After testing this program, we found that it is able to auto download and unzip the downloaded subtitle but the file name is kept the same. ALLSubtitleSearcher only support one database which is from OpenSubtitles.org.

---

Source: [5 Software to Easily Search for Correct Subtitle that Sync with Movies](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-search-for-correct-subtitle-that-sync-with-avi-movie/)

Answer (score 1):

I know of two free/open apps like that:

- [QNapi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qnapi/) - a small, quick app just like you describe, but AFAIK only downloads English and Polish subtitles for now
- [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) - a video player with integrated subtitle search for currently opened movie, also very quick. Multiple languages.